# Modify XML to Order Mid-level Complextype Elements by Name

Tags: sql, xml, sorting, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery

Edit: **See [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279846/order-xml-by-element-local-name-at-mid-level-xquery) for follow-up question**

I have a large `FOR XML EXPLICIT` query in SQL Server 2008 R2 that creates an xml file, but it is failing to validate against my XSD schema because some of the mid-level elements appear in the wrong order. Here is an example XML file to show what I mean:

```
<Things>
  <Thing>
    <Racecars>
      <Racecar>
        <Colour>Red</Colour>
        <Rockets>Y</Rockets>
      </Racecar>
      <Racecar>
        <Colour>Blue</Colour>
        <Rockets>N</Rockets>
      </Racecar>
    </Racecars>
  </Thing>
  <Thing>
    <Numbers>
      <Number>
        <NumericName>1</NumericName>
        <WrittenName>One</WrittenName>
      </Number>
      <Number>
        <NumericName>2</NumericName>
        <WrittenName>Two</WrittenName>
      </Number>
    </Numbers>
  </Thing>
  <Thing>
    <Letters>
      <Letter>
        <AlphaName>A</AlphaName>
        <PhoneticName>Ay</PhoneticName>
      </Letter>
      <Letter>
        <AlphaName>B</AlphaName>
        <PhoneticName>Bee</PhoneticName>
      </Letter>
    </Letters>
  </Thing>
</Things>
```

The way that the XML EXPLICIT command works means that each group containing some attributes are in order (the bottom level in this case), but I do not know how to control the order of the attributes directly below the (in this case) "Thing" Level. How can I specify that the child elements of "Thing" should appear in alphabetical order by name when there is no attribute data for SQL to ORDER BY?

As I mentioned, this is a big bit of XML, with many different elements, which do not always all appear, so if there were some way to order all of the child elements at a certain level, without affecting the ordering of the grandchild elements without having to hard-code each element name, that would be really great.

I have searched all over the place to no avail for a method. I have looked at both an ex post facto xquery modify on my XML output (which seems to me the most practical solution as some of the elements to be sorted have minOccurs = 0), or as part of the design of the FOR XML EXPLICIT command (which seems the most efficient as that way prevents rather than undoes the error) but, of what I have understood, nothing seems to work.

I could, of course, remove the  constraints from the schema file, but would much rather avoid this if at all possible as giving in to inexactitude seems the wrong direction to step.

With the above file, this is the outcome I would consider ideal:

```
<Things>
  <Thing>
    <Letters>
      <Letter>
        <AlphaName>A</AlphaName>
        <PhoneticName>Ay</PhoneticName>
      </Letter>
      <Letter>
        <AlphaName>B</AlphaName>
        <PhoneticName>Bee</PhoneticName>
      </Letter>
    </Letters>
  </Thing>
  <Thing>
    <Numbers>
      <Number>
        <NumericName>1</NumericName>
        <WrittenName>One</WrittenName>
      </Number>
      <Number>
        <NumericName>2</NumericName>
        <WrittenName>Two</WrittenName>
      </Number>
    </Numbers>
  </Thing>
  <Thing>
    <Racecars>
      <Racecar>
        <Colour>Red</Colour>
        <Rockets>Y</Rockets>
      </Racecar>
      <Racecar>
        <Colour>Blue</Colour>
        <Rockets>N</Rockets>
      </Racecar>
    </Racecars>
  </Thing>
</Things>
```

As you can see, the three elements below "Thing" are now sorted alphabetically (Letters,Numbers,Racecars) but all elements within each of these are unchanged in order.

Please let me know if you would like me to write out a `SELECT ... FOR XML EXPLICIT` to generate the example XML above; I will gladly do so - I just expected that the answer would be in the form of an xquery directly on the XML above, so thought it unlikely to be needed!

Comment: can you use FOR XML Path , also give sample data along with your current query to try out?

Comment: Don't really understand what your problem is. The only different between the 2 is that the first XML has `<Letters>` outside the `<Thing>` tag. The rest is the same: Letters, Numbers, Racecars.

Comment: Dammit! when editing the indents to make it look good in the post, I must have accidentally posted the same xml twice... bear with me. Right - I have edited the post. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reconstruct the `<Things/>` elements, ordering by the `<Thing/>`'s name. This snippet orders by the first child's name, as we need a single value to sort after. Regarding the input given, it does not seem necessary to order *inside* the `<Thing/>` (and might even be wrong).

```
element Things {
  for $thing in /Things/Thing
  let $name := local-name(($thing/*)[1])
  order by $name
  return $thing
}
```

Comment: Forgive me, I am a little confused about the context for this snippet - could you provide a little more information about how to apply the reconstruction, please? This is a steep learning curve for me I think! Should I be using your answer as part of an xquery and if so, where does it fit with the syntax? It looks like something else, but google is not much help so far...

Comment: This is the complete XQuery code applying the transformation you described above. `element Things { ... }` could also be writte as `<Things>{ ... }</Things>` and constructs the XML node. Inside, the snippet loops over all `<Thing/>`s and reorders them. Where and how to run the code inside a SQL query depends on how you store the data; if you can run any XQuery on the XML, just replace it.

Comment: I'm going to ask a new question; I think that my example was not great and I am getting errors when I try the suggested approach. When I change the syntax to match my (famously dangerous) little knowledge, I get something that works in this example, but not with the real data. I will link back to this question in the better written one.

Comment: Don't post follow-up information to your question as comments or answers, but edit your question instead. My bad; I accidentially included a syntax only supported by XQuery 3.0. I updated the snippet.