# Order xml by element local-name at mid level xquery

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery, flwor

I would like to re-order all of the elements of some xml, at a certain level, by the name of the element, but I am having a bit of trouble. Here is an example xml output I am working with (I'm using it in a variable @XML in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
<Data>
  <Uns>
    <Orgs>
      <Prods>
        <Prod>
          <Something>1</Something>
          <Cars>
            <Car>
              <Number>2013213</Number>
              <BasicInfo>
                <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
                <LastName>Monkhouse</LastName>
              </BasicInfo>
              <Anything>654</Anything>
            </Car>
            <Car>
              <Number>2013213</Number>
              <BasicInfo>
                <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
                <LastName>Monkhouse</LastName>
              </BasicInfo>
              <Anything>654</Anything>
            </Car>
          </Cars>
        </Prod>
        <Prod>
          <Cars>
            <Car>
              <Number>2013213</Number>
              <BasicInfo>
                <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
                <LastName>Monkhouse</LastName>
              </BasicInfo>
              <Anything>654</Anything>
            </Car>
          </Cars>
        </Prod>
       </Prods>
    </Orgs>
  </Uns>
</Data>
```

I would like to modify the order (in the example above) of all the child elements of `<Cars>` alphabetically, leaving their contents untouched. Following on from some help on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260920/modify-xml-to-order-mid-level-complextype-elements-by-name), where the answer gave ideas, but an error, I have got myself in a complete twist trying all sorts of variations on this:

```
select @XML.query('element Cars {
  for $anything in //Car
  order by local-name($anything/*[1])
  return $anything
}')
```

but nothing seems to be working. I find that I am constantly running up against a combination of these three problems: an error that says "The XQuery syntax '/function()' is not supported", losing all the parent elements (as the example above does) or nothing at all happening to the order (again as above). I am worried that I should be using `SET @XML.modify()` instead of `SELECT @XML.query()`, but that leads to even less results.

I have done a large amount of trawling on the internet, but none of the sites I have found seem to give a very complete understanding of the xquery FLWOR syntax - just specific and often simple examples are given, which have not helped me to find the solution as to why this is not behaving as I hoped.

Here is what the above xml would ideally look like after the transformation (the order of Number,BasicInfo and Anything is changed to be alphabetical):

```
<Data>
  <Uns>
    <Orgs>
      <Prods>
        <Prod>
            <Something>1</Something>
          <Cars>
            <Car>
              <Anything>654</Anything>
              <BasicInfo>
                <Name>Bob</Name>
              </BasicInfo>
              <Number>2013213</Number>
            </Car>
            <Car>
              <Anything>654</Anything>
              <BasicInfo>
                <Name>Bob</Name>
              </BasicInfo>
              <Number>2013213</Number>
            </Car>
          </Cars>
        </Prod>
        <Prod>
          <Cars>
            <Car>
              <Anything>654</Anything>
              <BasicInfo>
                <Name>Bob</Name>
              </BasicInfo>
              <Number>2013213</Number>
            </Car>
          </Cars>
        </Prod>
       </Prods>
    </Orgs>
  </Uns>
</Data>
```

Any help and advice much appreciated; I will keep searching online for a more complete understanding of the syntax and what exactly it is doing, but getting some kind of result would be a real boost at this stage!

Thanks!

Comment: Couple questions: why is node ordering important? where did you get the XML and any reason you can't manipulate it there before inserting into SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to reorder the elements within each `<Car/>` element, so will need two `for` loops. The following should work:

```xml
for $car in //Car
return <Car>{
  for $el in $car/*
  order by local-name($el)
  return $el
}</Car>
```

You will have to reconstruct the parent elements, as XQuery can not modify existing nodes (you would nee XQuery Update for that and I highly doubt SQL Server 2008 supports that).

However, please be adviced that I can hardly imagine what your reordering could be possibly used for. It represents the exact same information as before and each XML parser should not make a difference. I have never seen that someone wanted to simply reorder nodes, normally it would be done for same value of a node (e.g. reorder elements, so that the most expensive ones are first).

Comment: Ok, well that does what I asked for, so perfect - thanks! However, I take on board your comments and will consider changing the (perhaps overly restrictive) xsd schema that I wrote for the output. I will also see about persuading the company to get the latest version of the software so that I don't lose the parent elements. It seems that although you have answered my question, the real answer is that I need to look elsewhere in order to proceed. Damn. Thanks for the answer though!